# How do other players in my server know exactly where my most valuable items and cupboard are?

Tags: rust

For the second time our team base has been raided, using a raid tower.
We knew the weakness was there, but what confuses us is that for the second time they seemed to know exactly where our most valuable items and cupboard were.

Our base is quite a maze but they've managed to destroy the doors and walls that lead to the 'treasure' only, not a single other wall or door was harmed.

Is this really pure luck, twice in a row? (And twice with different bases, different setups) or is this cheating? A trick maybe?

Comment: Have you excluded the possiblity of a mole? Or worse, a dual-account meta-gamer?

Comment: @Oak I highly doubt it's a mole since we're 3 friends that know each other outside of gaming as well and the raiding happened in the middle of the night. We all have fulltime jobs.

Comment: Was the cupboard close enough to an outside wall/roof where someone could utilize screen-clipping as a tactic for determining where your cupboard was? I've experienced that accidentally myself, but could easily see how that could be used as a tactic to find something through walls.

Comment: Have you tried asking the raiders?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things I could imagine:

- That your base design was simply "Cupboard and loot in the center on the ground floor".
- That it was a design made on Youtube.
- That they knew it due to experience on raiding in Rust.
- That the Cupboard was next to an outside wall and they could look through.
- That they got help by an admin.
- That you guys got betrayed.

I have been playing Rust for about 2,5k hours now and for most of the bases I saw, I already knew where the loot might be. Just due to experience! This would be the most likely answer!

A Blueprint and the Server you played on would definitely help to get an answer :)

Comment: This answers the question with some possible answers but you've also included a request for more information which is more of a comment. Could you [edit] this to read more as an answer rather than a comment which this reads like. This site is a question and answer site not a discussion forum so answers should only be used to answer the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sadly I cannot comment until 50 reputations, but I changed it! Hopefully this works better, otherwise I would delete it, because nobody could deliver the right answer without knowing the Base, he talked about

Comment: Aye that seems to help! Please refrain from posting comments as answers though until you hit 50 rep. If you do that you're likely to hit an answer ban which we don't want!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Okay, thanks alot! I will take care of delivering proper comments and answers

Comment: There's also the possibility that they were betrayed.